# Facebook thumbnail doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata

I have a url which works fine and when I go to [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) It loads all the data correct in the debugger.

Here is what appears to me in debugger

[image]

It doesn't work when share on facebook, nothing shows up, not an image, not an article and no description.

Comment: It takes some time for facebook to update this

Answer (score 0):

Your Link
works fine for me in Facebook. Prove:

[image: Facebook Link with Text and Image]